# Matlab pattern match using imdilate and imerode

Tags: matlab, binary, design-patterns, match

im new to Matlab so this should be a simple question.

I want to search a binary image for a specific pattern. Lets say I´m looking for the pattern [1 0; 0 1; 1 0; 0 1]. I made a structuring element with strel with the specific pattern. When i use imerode with this pattern, it will match the zeros but ignores the ones, for example it will match [0 0; 0 0; 0 0; 0 0] too .The same applies for imdilate with ones How can i combine the two at the same time to find the exact pattern of 1s and 0s.
I have already tried imopen and imclose and it does not work.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Pattern match in binary image can be done using bwhitmiss (hit-miss operation). It accepts a kernel that contain ones(1) zeros(-1) and don´t care(0) elements.

http://www.mathworks.es/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwhitmiss.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use `strfind` command to match the pattern. If you have an array `A`, and you need to match a pattern in `B`, 
`strfind(A B)` will return the index of the match in `A`

Comment: What i have is a binary image (matrix of ones an zeros) strfind won´t work there.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for the ignorance. I thought it would work for the images. But still, in principle you can use strfind to do pattern matching row/column wise